# Slichos, netz and nusach

Tags: nuschaot, priorities, selichot

A person who is ashkenaz (father ashkenaz, mother sephardi) has the habit of praying netz with the only minyan in his area that does, and it is a sephardi minyan. In order to not be different than the tsibur, and for additional chizuk, he does sephardi slichos from chodesh elul. When ashkenaz slichos begin, he does ashkenaz slichos on the first motzei shabbos. The days after, he has a serious shayla: while he wants to do ashkenazi slichos, no ashkenazi shul starts them early enough for him to make netz tefillah with that shul. Should he

(i) do sephardi slichos before netz and daven sephardi netz; 
(ii) do sephardi netz and daven ashkenazi slichos in a later minyan; or 
(iii) daven ashkenazi slichos and ashkenazi teffilh at a time that is not netz?

He believes the answer is option (i) because:

- prayer is do e more often than slichos and should take priority
- praying netz thus is most important
- when give the choice between the nusach and the time, the earlier time should trump because early morning is a more favorable time in halacha, especially for slichis when we look for an es ratzon

What sources support each possibility (or any other possibility)?

Comment: Is there a reason why he can't say Sfardi selichot and shaharit and then go to the Ashkenazi minyan for selichot?

Comment: This appears to be a question of minhag. Both Ashkenazim and Sefardim hold the same way. Namely that אל תטוש את תורת אמך. He can daven with the neitz minyan. It doesn't require him to change his nusach unless he was davening from the amud.