# Davening Netz or Selichos

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, priorities, selichot, hanetz-sunrise

If a person has the opportunity of davening netz, but doing so would require putting off the recitation of selichos (since it's nearly netz), does the fulfillment of davening in the optimal way supersede the usual order of reciting selichos before morning prayers?

Might we say that davening netz is a "zmano oveir" vs. the recitation of selichos before shacharis, which (already being post-alos) may be said bedi'eved through the rest of the day?

Related to [this closed question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/63732/slichos-netz-and-nusach) and [this link](http://jewishworker.blogspot.com/2005/09/when-is-proper-time-to-say-selichos.html) from another [related question.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9607/saying-selichos-before-midnight)

Comment: Can you clarify regarding Minyan: Is either way he will pray with a Minyan? Are the Selichot with a Minyan?

Comment: @DoubleAA In this case I was assuming selichos and davening would be identical - either a minyan for both or neither. Given that, is there a substantive difference between those circumstances that warrants restricting the question?

Comment: Davening Netz has priority over davening with a Minyan. And Selichot. No time for sources now.

Comment: @DannySchoemann So you're saying that Netz has priority over Selichos, and that if one must choose between them choose Netz?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky - yes. Remember a Mishna where one "davens Netz" while immersed in the Mikveh? that's how important this Torah Mitzva is. Selichos is a later "addition".

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky - http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01790.html - יז. סדר החשיבות: א. תפילה בנץ. ב. תיקון חצות. ג. אמירת סליחות, כשמתפלל בנץ וקשה להשכים עוד עבור סליחות יאמרו סליחות אחרי שחרית או אחה"צ.  (No idea who this is written by and what his source are.)

Comment: Should'nt tadir v'sheino tadir apply. The more frequent mitzvah comes 1st. That may be the case even later in the day

Answer (score 4):

Rav Chaim Kanivesky (Daas Noteh 1:page 192:10) was asked this question. He answered  "with certainty davening vasikin(source in gemara) is more important than selichos(just a minhag),but the main mitzvah of selichos is b'ashmoros haboker"

Comment: +1 I wonder what Reb Moshe would say considering he believes we can't really figure out when Netz is.